# Run a function when modal opens

Tags: vue.js

OK, so this is the deal. I have a sidebar that when I click on a button a modal shows up in the middle of the screen. This modal receives its data from an axios.get call inside a function.

What I want is if the modal closes and the user opens it up again, it refreshes the data from the function. What do I do?

to be clear - all the code that is to be invoked including the data array is inside the modal.

Comment: Watch the property that toggles the modal open/close.

Comment: If your modal is in a component by its self, use the `beforeDetroy` hook of the component to cleanup the data.

Comment: If you're watching the property that opens and closes the modal, you may face a delay in data loading. In this case, make sure to turn the `immediate` flag of `watch` to true. [https://vuejs.org/v2/api/](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/)